# Unit testing wordpress plugins with plugin options

Tags: plugin-development, unit-tests

I'm new with unit testing in Wordpress. I managed to setup the unit testing environment using PHP Unit and [Wordpress tests](https://github.com/nb/wordpress-tests) but I am having trouble accessing the plugin options that I've set in the plugin.

```
class nrw_pg{

  private $twitter_id;

  public function __construct(){
    $options = get_option('nrw_pg_options');
    $this->twitter_id = (!empty($options['nrw_pg_options_twitter_id'])) ? $options['nrw_pg_options_twitter_id'] : '';

  }

  public function get_tweets(){
     $result = null;
     $protocol = is_SSL() ? 'https://' : 'http://';
     $result = wp_remote_get($this->protocol . "api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=". $this->twitter_id."&count=11&exclude_replies=true");

     return $result;
   }
}

$GLOBALS['nrw_pg'] = new nrw_pg();
```

It all works smoothly when accessing it from the browser. But on the unit tests it doesn't seem like it has knowledge of the options that I have set.

```
require_once('D:\web_files\tester\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\nrw_pg\nrw_pg.php');

class Nrw_Pg_Test extends WP_UnitTestCase {
    public $plugin_slug = 'nrw_pg';
    public $options;

    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->nrw_pg = $GLOBALS['nrw_pg'];

    }

    public function test_get_tweets(){

        $this->assertNotNull($this->nrw_pg->connect());
    }

}
```

Is there anything else that I need to setup aside from the wp-test-config.php and other things mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138215/unit-testing-wordpress-plugins in order to make this work?

It seems like other things are working like testing if specific filters are added. But the options it doesn't seem like they have been initialized. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the testing database is (usually, and should be) a separate database, you will need to set the appropriate option value in the setUp routine (using add_option or update_option).

I would also recommend deleting or reseting the option in the teardown method as well, but I have had issues when trying to drop tables (see [Plugin development with unit tests](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94954/plugin-development-with-unit-tests)).

Comment: so does this mean I'll just have to use the test database instead while doing the testing? I just changed the database in the wp-config.php to be the same as the one used in the config for testing and then created the options that I need on the setUp.

Comment: I would recommend that. The tests that I write involve changing the database (inserting and updating posts etc) and I'd rather they not mess with my development environments.

Comment: Update: for those who want to use a separate database and have the option to quickly scaffold, check out http://wp-cli.org/commands/scaffold/plugin-tests/ --being that it contains a shell script to generate a wordpress testing environment from within /tmp/.